# PowerShell: Remove all permissions from a file incl. APPLICATION PACKAGES

Tags: powershell, permissions

I want to remove **all** permissions from some Windows\System32-files, e.g. wuauclt.exe and wuaueng.dll. Therefore I found that script:

```
takeown /F $file
$acl = get-acl $file
$acl.Access | % {$acl.purgeaccessrules($_.IdentityReference)}
Set-Acl -aclobject $acl -Path $file
```

This gives me ownership and removes all permission except those for ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES and ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES. How am I able remove those as well per PowerShell script (not manually and without using a 3rd party tool)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code, as is, and assuming this is ran from an elevated powershell session should remove all ACLs except for `$acl.Owner`, `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` and `BUILTIN\Administrators`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `IdentityReference` are specific. In fact it is an instance of `[System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]` and translating them to a `[System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]` output an error.
But it is still possible to create them manually.
In SDDL format:

- `AC` or `S-1-15-2-1` for `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES`
- `S-1-15-2-2` for `ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES`

You can add the following code to remove them. But I'm not sure this is a good idea to remove these rights on System files.

```
$acl.Access | % {
    if ($_.IdentityReference.Value -imatch "APPLICATION PACKAGES") {
        try {
            $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new("S-1-15-2-2")) 
            $acl.PurgeAccessRules([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new("AC"))
        } catch { }
    }
    else {
        $acl.purgeaccessrules($_.IdentityReference)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works on English systems but I have struggles on my German system. Not only the `-imatch` value is different but the `AC` or `S-1-15-2-1` for `ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES` just does not work. Could you give me a hint how I would be able to find out the SDDL format which is used here? By the way, I do not have the `Get-Member` function in the powershell if this should be needed.

Comment: After further testing, your essential script is also working on my German system but the special permissions for AC are restored and therefore $ACL is not correctly set. Even manually there is no way to remove AC completely. Why is this so in a German system while it is possible in an English system?

Comment: On system files there may be additional protections that may restore them. But no reason this would work on English systems vs German systems. Nevertheless the display name of the security identity may be different like `Administrators` on English systems and `Administrateurs` on French ones. That's why the well-known SID or SDDL format is better. [AC](https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/f4296d69-1c0f-491f-9587-a960b292d070) SDDL. [Well-known SID](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-dtyp/81d92bba-d22b-4a8c-908a-554ab29148ab)